# What does the constant E do in the c language

Tags: c

When I run the code below

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
    double n = 2E-1;
    printf("%d",n);
}
```

When I run the code it prints a weird number instead of 0.2(2E-1).

Comment: `"%f"` is the correct format specifier to print a `double`.

Comment: It's the [E-Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E-notation). `E` is not a constant.

Comment: Possibly - I'm not sure which part (the exponential notation or the printing) is more important to OP.

Comment: [What does the numerical literal 0.e0f mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24777846/995714), [How is the 'E/e' in hexadecimal differentiated from the 'E/e' in exponential form in a hexadecimal floating point literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38412560/995714). And your code above almost definitely doesn't produce 0.2 or 2e-1, since you're printing a double with `%d`

Comment: @k0na What compiler are you using that does not warn about `double n = ...;
    printf("%d",n);`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What does the constant E do in the c language

The documentation for floating-point constants is [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/floating_constant).

The form `1e2` or `1E2` means *`1` times ten to the power of `2`*, and you're perfectly correct that `2E-1` means *`2` times ten to the power of `-1`*, or `0.2`.

It's based on the scientific E notation linked by Eugene.

> When I run the code it prints a weird number

That's just because you used the wrong format specifier. These are documented [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), and you can see you should use one of `eEfFgG` for doubles.

Answer (score 0):

In C language, for double, the format specifier is `%lf`

So, if you use `%lf` then it will print `n` as `0.200000`

And if you use `%g` or `%G` (as supported data types are float, double) then the output will be `0.2`

Comment: the format specifier for double in printf is `%f`. `%lf` is just an alias